# Secant line slope question

Tags: calculus

I am asked to:

Show the expression for the slope of the secant line through $y=x^2+3x$ at $x=3$ and $x=3+h$ is $msec=9+h$

\begin{align*}
 msec &= \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
 &= \dfrac{(x+h)^2+3(x+h)-(x^2+3x)}{h}\\
 &=\dfrac{(x+h)(x+h)+3x+3h-x^2-3x}{h}\\
 &=\dfrac{2xh+h^2+3h}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{h(2x+h+3)}{h}\\
&=2x+h+3
\end{align*}

The first part seems to work:
\begin{align*}
msec&=2(3)+h+3\\
&=9+h
\end{align*}

Second part: \begin{align*}
msec&=2(3+h)+h+3\\
&=6+2h+h+3\\
&=3h+9
\end{align*}

Am I missing something or is this a mistake / flaw in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing less that you think. On the line where you conclude with $2x+h+3$, you need to stop, and insert $x=3$ to get $9+h$, and then conclude. There is nothing else left to do. There is no second part.

Comment: The question asks to show at $x=3$ and $x=3+h$ though.

Comment: nitrous2, I understand. This is the definition of the secant line through two points. In this definition, you do not plug both points into the $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. This formula is already derived so that you just plug in the left point. The $x+h$ is already accounted for in the formula. There is only one slope between the two points. You found it when you concluded the first part. There really is nothing left for you to do after that (I teach college level calculus :)) trust me ;)).

Comment: It is possible that "between the two points", or "over the two points" would have left the question clearer for you. There is only one secant line through two points, and you found its slope.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thanks!

Comment: the second part is calculating the slope of the secant line through the points $(x+h,f(x+h))$ and $((x+h)+h, f((x+h)+h))$